# jquery $(td) exclude colspan?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi. I have the following that adds a class to all `<td>` elements, however I have a particular `<td colspan="3">` and I want to exclude it. How do I do this in jquery? Thanks for any help.

```
$('td', table).addClass('ui-widget-content'); // exclude a <td colspan="3">
```

Comment: sorry stackoverflow seems to remove html tag in my comment??? My question should be: Hi I have the following that adds a class to all "td tag" however I have a particular "td tag colspan=6" and I want to exclude it. How do I do this in jquery? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've edited your question to display the missing tag details, but (with my current priveleges) I have to wait for that edit to be peer reviewed before you'll see it. If you enclose your tags with the ` character they will display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.not()` to exclude particular elements.

```
$('td', table).not('td [colspan=3]').addClass('ui-widget-content');
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! I have to wait 5mins to accept the answer :(
Whats wrong with stackoverflow?

Comment: 'td colspan:3' is not the correct selector expression, should be 'td[colspan=3]'

Answer (score 2):

This is more cleanly done in my opinion using an attribute selector

```
$('td[colspan!=6]', table).addClass('ui-widget-content');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter function (See manual here http://api.jquery.com/filter/ )

Answer (score 0):

Could do it in selector

`$('td:not([colspan=3])','table').addClass('ui-widget-content');`

[see example](http://jsfiddle.net/2vK3p/)

Answer (score 0):

Use not()

```
$('td', table).not('td [colspan=3]').addClass('ui-widget-content');
```